# How to design Floating tool bar in Qt 4.5.2

Tags: linux, qt, qt4

How to make Floating tool bar in Qt, just like the top floating panel of Microsoft Windows RDP client, any code example?
Regards

Answer (score 4):

Inside your QMainWindow derived class:

```
QToolBar* pToolBar = new QToolBar(this);

pToolBar->setAllowedAreas(Qt::NoToolBarArea);

pToolbar->setFixedWidth(300);
pToolBar->setFixedHeight(50);

/* add actions to pToolBar here */

addToolBar(Qt::NoToolBarArea, pToolBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it myself - from scratch. AFAIk none of the existing Qt widgets will give you what you want. However, it should be trivially easy to subclass QWidget and create your own.

Comment: the main window of my application is child of QWidget, how to make toolbar the child of QWidget???